# Powershell script copy itself to another location

Tags: powershell

Is this possible? I'm building a script but I can't seem to figure it out.
I want the script to write itself to the disk. Or write itself to another location.
Thanks in advance

Comment: see Get-Content and Out-File

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Im new to coding so it is a bit difficult for me to understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on the question instead. E.g. where does the script from (a file location?, internet?, memory?). See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the automatic [`$MyInvocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) variable:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptContents | Out-File .\MyCopy.ps1
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I did! thank you very much :)!  Also. Do you know how to do this when the script is converted to an executable? With like PS2EXE?